# Sequelize - handling foreignKey 'Null' Value

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a form that input from a web page and handle it with sequelize. foreignKey using a select form, so if the user didn't select, i want return constraint/validation error with msg "is required"

here on my model

```
    categoryId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: { 
        args: false,
        msg: 'Category are required' 
      },
```

but it's not returning the constraint/validation error.

its return like this

`DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: invalid input syntax for type integer: "null"`

how to handle that?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the official [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html#allowing-disallowing-null-values)

- If a particular field of a model is set to not allow null (with
  allowNull: false) and that value has been set to null, all validators
  will be skipped and a ValidationError will be thrown.
- On the other hand, if it is set to allow null (with allowNull: true)
  and that value has been set to null, only the built-in validators
  will be skipped, while the custom validators will still run.

  categoryId: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: true,
  validate: {
  notNull: {
  msg: 'Category are required'
  }
  }